# Apache tiles css

Tags: spring, apache, jsp, tiles

I cannot load the css files. Try almost all way to reach it. Could someone advice where should be the problem. Thanks in advance.

tiles-definitions where is defined tiles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="defaultTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/template/default/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/body.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/footer.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="stylesheets" value="/src/main/resources/css/layout.css" />            
    </definition>


</tiles-definitions>
```

template.jsp is defalut template:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Default tiles template</title>
     <c:forEach var="css" items="${stylesheets}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="${css}"/>">
    </c:forEach>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">

        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />

        <div class="content">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
        </div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

welcomepage.jsp using template.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<tiles:importAttribute name="stylesheets"/>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Default tiles template</title>
     <c:forEach var="css" items="${stylesheets}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="${css}"/>">
    </c:forEach>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">

        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />

        <div class="content">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
        </div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

dispatcher-sevrlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

   <tx:annotation-driven/>

   <mvc:annotation-driven />

   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

  <context:component-scan base-package="intranetwebapp.*" />

  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
      <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
      <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
  </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/intranetwebapp" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="gargamel" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop 
         key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="intranetwebapp.entity" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
  </bean>



  <!-- Tiles configuration -->

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't this be single quotes  .. `"${css}"`. Also you dont need `/src/main/` in the variable.. Also, `${stylesheets}` is not an array, but you are trying to iterate over it..

Answer (score 0):

can you try something like below,

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Default tiles template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/layout.css'/>">
</head>
```

or you can set `stylesheet` variable to `/resources/css/layout.css` in spring model object and set the value in c:url to `value='${stylesheet}'` in jsp.

Comment: I try your solution, but it does not work too. I think it must be problem somewhere in path

Comment: oops... this wont work because you are giving the jsp notation to read a tiles variable. why cant you hard code the stylesheet path?

Comment: So I should delete attribute "stylesheets" from tiles-defitions and then could be work it ?

Comment: you should delete that from tiles and put it in `ModelMap` object in a controller (if you want to reference the path using variable).. or you can use an interceptor for adding the variable to session.. But i recommend you to hard code the css files in the `template.jsp` like i mentioned in the answer (in that case you can completely get rid of `stylesheets` variable)...

Comment: I did the last option of hard code and when the page is loaded, in web browser developer I can see in html code that the css link is like:          `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/IntranetWebApp/src/main/resources/css/layout.css">)`. And still does not work.

Comment: `/src/main/` this part shouldn't come... just for testing, can you change the code to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/IntranetWebApp/resources/css/layout.css">`  (without the c:url)..

Comment: I did it and still not work. Above I put my tree sctructure if you would find some mistake there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96565/discussion-between-redflar3-and-user3770144).